# How do I convert NSString to rgbValue and pass that as value as parameter for UIColorFromRGB?

Tags: uicolor

I'm working on an application where a color code such as (#ff0000) is read from an xml file in the documents dir. I have defined a Macro UIColorFromRGB which is also working fine when I pass the color code directly as below:

bgView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff0000);

What should I Change if I have to pass the code as below:

bgView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(mycolor);

where (mycolor) is NSString obj that contains value (#ff0000) obtained from the xml file?

Greatly appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSScanner` has a `-scanHexInt:` method that you can use to convert the string into an integer.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:mycolor];
if ([scanner scanString:@"#" intoString:NULL]) {
    unsigned int colorValue = 0;
    if ([scanner scanHexInt:&colorValue]) {
        ...
    }
}
```